# Does anyone know the style of connector used on Ford CFI throttle body injectors?

Tags: ford, wiring, fuel-injection, fuel-injectors

I am trying to find the part number on a connector for the injectors used on Ford's throttle body injection. This connector is on a Bosch injector made for Ford's CFI throttle body injection used on cars and trucks from 1980-1987. Some Taurus models used it until 1990. BOSCH TBI 0280150601 is one example.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Jeez, haven't seen one of those in a while, most are in junk yards by now. The was an old tsb on the early ones where the o-ring failed on the injector and poured fuel in the intake.

Answer (score 1):

I found two part numbers for you:

- Standard Motor Products - PN: S685
- WVE/Aiirtex/Wells - PN: 1P1005

The end of the Standard Motor Products looks like this:

[image: From RockAuto.com]